# FluentNHibernate SchemaUpdate isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

I have a problem updating the database schema using SchemaUpdate method of FluentNHibernate.
Here's my code:

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration
  .MsSql2012.ShowSql()
  .ConnectionString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
  .AddFromAssemblyOf<LanguageMap>()
  .AddFromAssemblyOf<RoleMap>()
//(...)
  )
    //.ExposeConfiguration(CreateSchema)
  .ExposeConfiguration(UpdateSchema)
  .BuildConfiguration();
```

The CreateSchema method looks like this:

```
private static void CreateSchema(Configuration cfg)
{
    var schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
    schemaExport.Execute(false, true, true);
    schemaExport.Drop(false, true);
    schemaExport.Create(false, true);
}
```

And the UpdateSchema like this:

```
private static void UpdateSchema(Configuration cfg)
{
    var schemaUpdate = new SchemaUpdate(cfg);
    schemaUpdate.Execute(false, true);
    var ex = schemaUpdate.Exceptions;
}
```

Now CreateSchema works OK - tables are being created properly. The problem is with UpdateSchema, which is not working. So far I was able to diagnose what's wrong by checking the schemaUpdate.Exceptions, which contains 2 entries, both with the same exception :

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'."}
```

From what I've read, sys.sequences is a new feature in SQL Server 2012, but I don't know how this table (is this a system table?) should be created (shouldn't it be created when creating the database?). Could this be a problem of version conflict of something? I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express, .NET Framework 4.5, NHibernate 3.3.1.4 and FluentNHibernate 1.3

---------------------- **EDIT** -------------------------

Ok my mistake, I was actually connected to 2008 version os SQL Server, that's why sys.sequences (now I also know it is a system view) was not available. Still, I would want SchemaUpdate to work on 2008, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the problem lies in compatibility of SQL Server, and the solution, when I figured it out, is rather obvious:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
```

It simply has to be changed to 2008 and it's working.
[This is where it breaks with 2012 configuration on 2008](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2012Dialect.cs) since 2008 doesn't have the sys.seuences view